# How to add to JSON array in .json file

Tags: php, json, file, arrays

How do I add to a .json file with PHP? Currently, I'm appending a .json file with PHP, but it won't add the data to an existing JSON object. It makes a new object. I need the data all stored in one object, in an external JSON file. Basically, I have a JSON object and want to add more values to it.

```
$jsonFile = "test.json";
$fh = fopen($jsonFile, 'w');

$json = json_encode(array("message" => $name, "latitude" => $lat, "longitude" => $lon, "it" => $it));

fwrite($fh, $json);
```

Comment: I would `json_decode` it, `array_merge` it with the new array, and then `json_encode` it again.

Comment: Your saying to retrieve whats already there, then merge and re-encode the arrays? Then, re write it to the json file?

Comment: Precisely. I am not aware of any feasible in-place transformation that you might use.

Comment: As long as the data gets merged, I'm ok.

Comment: I've to say that mysql functions are absolete, use PDO or mysqli functions instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can decode the json file to a php array, then insert new data and save it again.

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data = json_decode($file);
unset($file);//prevent memory leaks for large json.
//insert data here
$data[] = array('data'=>'some data');
//save the file
file_put_contents('data.json',json_encode($data));
unset($data);//release memory
```

Answer (score 2):

what's suggested above is the hard way. i am considering there should be an easier way, to literally append an array into the json file.

here is the algo:

```
$handle=fopen($jsonFile);
fseek($handle,-1,SEEK_END);
fwrite($handle,$arrayToAdd);
fclose($handle);
```

but i am not sure it's more cpu/memory efficient to do so than reading the whole json file into memory, adding the array and then getting it stored.

Comment: Yes it did waste much less memory & CPU to do so. However when the data structure changes you need to modify your code for that.